# How to get part of string after some word with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string containing a path:

```
/var/www/project/data/path/to/file.mp3
```

I need to get the substring starting with '/data' and delete all before it. So, I need to get only `/data/path/to/file.mp3`.

What would be the fastest solution?

Answer (score 6):

```
'/var/www/project/data/path/to/file.mp3'.match(/\/data.*/)[0]
=> "/data/path/to/file.mp3"
```

Comment: This can be simplified to: `'/var/www/project/data/path/to/file.mp3'[%r[(/data.*)], 1]`

Comment: @theTinMan, cool thing, even couldn't think that it can be possible

Answer (score 3):

could be as easy as:

```
string = '/var/www/project/data/path/to/file.mp3'

path = string[/\/data.*/]

puts path
=> /data/path/to/file.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression is a good way. Though I am not familiar with ruby, I think ruby should have some function like "substring()"(maybe another name in ruby).

Here is a demo by using javascript:

```
var str = "/var/www/project/data/path/to/file.mp3";
var startIndex = str.indexOf("/data");
var result = str.substring(startIndex );
```

And the link on jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S2Rfy/2/)

I think the code in ruby is similar, you can check the documentation. Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
"/var/www/project/data/path/to/file.mp3".scan(/\/var\/www(\/.+)*/)
```

It should return you all occurrences.